# php - foreach loop, custom slide

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

It should be a slider, which shows all posts, but only 15 posts on each slide. I get all Posts.

(I use Wordpress functions.)

In the -div class = "slide"- there are 15 posts, after that a new -div class = "slide"- with 15 posts should be created.

Here is the code for all posts:

```
$myposts = get_posts($args);




$result = '<div id="fullpage">';
    $result .= '<div class="section" id="section1">';

        $result .= '<div class="slide">';
            foreach ($myposts as $post) {
                $result .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
                 //        the_post_thumbnail('full');
            }

        $result .= '</div>';
    $result .= ' </div>';

$result .= '</div>';


return $result;
```

After 15 posts, I would like a new slide. I do not know how to adjust the foreach loop. Should I do this with an if statement, or can I do this with a foreach loop?

Comment: You can add counter in foreach  and if condition to check counter value 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter, and reset it after 15. (Not tested, I have no PHP at the moment)

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($myposts as $post) {
    if ($counter == 1) {
        $result .= '<div class="slide">';
    }
    $result .= '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == 16) {
        $counter = 1;
        $result .= '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! :) Just what I need.